# Verificar se um "String resource" está sendo usada no projeto

Tags: android, eclipse

#### Situação

Quando não usamos uma variável no arquivo, o **Eclipse** tem uma funcionalidade que trata-se informar o desenvolvedor emitindo a seguinte mensagem:

> The value of the field Classe.ClienteId is not used.

Veja a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Do mesmo modo, existe uma forma saber se um item não está sendo usado no arquivo `res/values/strings` no **Eclipse**? Como por exemplo o `txt_button_enter` como mostra abaixo:

```
<string name="txt_button_enter">Enter</string>
```

Antecipadamente agradeço.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para verificar no Eclipse, faça o seguinte:

1. De um click com o botão direito no nome do projeto e selecione **Package explorer**
2. Selecione **Android Tools**
3. Selecione **Run Lint: Check for common Errors**

Agora quando você abrir o seu arquivo **strings.xml**, você verá tudo que não estiver sendo usado em destaque.

Comment: Não tinha usado essa funcionalidade ainda. Vlw. Obrigado!